# Matrix operation to count nonzero elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I require a function to count the nonzero elements in an integer-valued matrix $A\in \mathbb {N}^{n\times n}$.

I am aware that the standard approach would be to define a binary matrix $B\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ such that:
$$b_{ij}=\begin{cases}1&if&a_{ij}\ne0\\0&if&a_{ij}=0 \end{cases}$$

and then sum the elements $\sum_{ij}b_{ij}$. However, this function complicates later analysis. Are there any operations which could achieve this through matrix multiplication?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have 2 ways to look at this & with either way , I get the Same Conclusion : We can not achieve this through matrix multiplication alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct the diagonal matrix $$D = {\rm Diag}({\rm vec}(A))$$
Then the desired function is $${\rm trace}(D^+D)$$
where $D^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse.

---

If you allow *element-wise* functions, then another possibility is
$${\tt1}^T {\,\rm sign}({\rm abs}(A))\,{\tt1}$$
where ${\tt1}$ is the all-ones vector.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it is not possible, simply because counting non-zero entries is not a linear operation: If you scale your whole matrix $A$ by the number $2$, then the number of non-zero entries does not double.

If you preprocess your matrix $A$ by replacing every non-zero entry by $1$, as you described, then it is possible: Suppose that $B \in \{0,1\}^{n\times n}$. Then the sum of all entries (which is the number of non-zero entries) is $v^T B v$ where $v = (1, \dots, 1)^T$ is the vector with $n$ ones.

Answer (score 0):

Another element-wise possibility to convert nonnegative matrix $A\in \mathbb 
 R _+^{n\times n}$ to nonzero is $$B=1-0^A$$
Then the sum of nonzero elements is given by
$$1^TB1$$